# How to get data from spinner

Tags: android, android-intent, spinner

I need to get the data from a spinner and myCalendar activities how to get data from it and main activity to be able to process data and input it as email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by myCalendar activities? Can you post the code?

As for your spinner:

You need to attach a setOnItemSelectedListener() to your Spinner object and then override the onItemSelected method in it.

Here is an example: here I have a spinner that has int values for minute (0-60). It saves the value that the user selected in an int. This could be modified to anything you want, same principle.

```
Spinner spinnerMinute = findViewById(R.id.spinner_minute);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapterMinute = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, presetListMinute);

    adapterMinute.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinnerMinute.setAdapter(adapterMinute);
        spinnerMinute.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    minute = Integer.toString(i);

            }
```

Here presetListMinute is a simple ArrayList containing the minute values (from 0 to 60)
i in the Listener is the index in the the list that the user selected.

Comment: i use CalendarView to view the date of the week

Comment: here's the code snippet <br>simpleCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                // Display the selected date by using toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });